Understanding Analogies Between Fourier Transform and Ricci Tensor Definition
I'm trying to understand the similarities between the Fourier transform in quantum mechanics and the definition of the Ricci tensor in differential geometry. Specifically, I'm interested in the analogy between the $x$ and $p$ variables in the Fourier transform and the $Y$ and $Z$ vectors in the Ricci tensor definition.
In the Fourier transform:
$$ \phi(p) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}} \int e^{-ipx/\hbar} \psi(x) \, dx, $$
In the Ricci tensor definition:
$$ \text{Ric}_p(Y, Z) = \sum_{i=1}^n \langle R_p(v_i, Y)Z, v_i \rangle, $$
How do the roles of $x$ and $p$ in the Fourier transform relate to the roles of $Y$ and $Z$ in the Ricci tensor definition? What are the key parallels and analogous quantities in these two contexts?
The reason I am interested because of the following. The Fourier transform and the Ricci tensor definition share structural similarities in how they project functions or tensors onto a basis and sum the contributions to transform the representation. Here’s a breakdown of the analogous quantities and roles:
Fourier Transform Context:
$$ \phi(p) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}} \int e^{-ipx/\hbar} \psi(x) \, dx $$

$x$ and $p$: Position and momentum variables, respectively.
$\psi(x)$: Wavefunction in position space.
$\phi(p)$: Wavefunction in momentum space.
$e^{-ipx/\hbar}$: Basis functions in Fourier space.
Integral: Sums the contributions of $\psi(x)$ projected onto the basis functions.

Ricci Tensor Context:
$$ \text{Ric}_p(Y, Z) = \sum_{i=1}^n \langle R_p(v_i, Y)Z, v_i \rangle $$

$Y$ and $Z$: Tangent vectors at point $p$ on the manifold.
$R_p(v_i, Y)Z$: Action of the Riemann curvature tensor.
$\langle R_p(v_i, Y)Z, v_i \rangle$: Inner product with basis vector $v_i$.
$v_i$: Orthonormal basis vectors in the tangent space.
Summation: Sums the contributions of the curvature tensor projected onto the basis vectors.

Key Parallels:

Variables $x$ and $p$ vs. Tangent Vectors $Y$ and $Z$:

$x$ and $p$ are dual variables linked through the wavefunctions $\psi(x)$ and $\phi(p)$.
$Y$ and $Z$ are tangent vectors linked through the curvature tensor $R_p$.


Wavefunctions $\psi(x)$ and $\phi(p)$ vs. Curvature Tensor $R_p(v_i, Y)Z$:

$\psi(x)$ and $\phi(p)$ represent the same quantum state in different domains.
$R_p(v_i, Y)Z$ represents the curvature's effect on tangent vectors.


Basis Functions $e^{-ipx/\hbar}$ vs. Basis Vectors $v_i$:

Complex exponentials $e^{-ipx/\hbar}$ serve as basis functions in Fourier analysis.
Vectors $v_i$ serve as the orthonormal basis in the tangent space.


Integral vs. Summation:

The integral in the Fourier transform sums the continuous contributions of $\psi(x)$.
The summation in the Ricci tensor definition sums the discrete contributions of $R_p$.



Both operations involve transforming an entity (a function or a tensor) by projecting onto a basis, summing the contributions, and thus changing the representation. The Fourier transform converts between position and momentum spaces, while the Ricci tensor projection converts the Riemann curvature tensor into a scalar quantity that forms the Ricci tensor.
Question:
How do the roles of the variables $x$ and $p$ in the Fourier transform relate to the roles of the tangent vectors $Y$ and $Z$ in the Ricci tensor definition? And why are there these analogies?

There isn't any deep connection between these two concepts. At best, you can say that they have a vaguely similar form because you can think of both the Fourier transform and the Ricci tensor as linear maps. But that's true of a lot of things, not just these two concepts.
